# Symfony Postgresql Postgis Find elements around

Tags: postgresql, symfony, postgis

I am trying to use postgis to find some stuff around a point with distance expressed in meters.

I am on Symfony 6.3.7, doctrine bundle 2.10, postresql 13 and postgis 3.0
I also installed jsor bundle for doctrine extensions, here is my conf:

```yaml
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                ST_DWithin: Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\ST_DWithin
                ST_SetSRID: Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\ST_SetSRID
                ST_POINT: Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\ST_Point
                ST_GeomFromText: Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\ST_GeomFromText
                ST_Transform: Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\ST_Transform
                geometry: Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\Geometry
                geography: Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\Geography
```

I have on my database two cols with longitude and latitude.
I created a DoctrineMigration with the following requests to create a point column.
I choose the SRID 4326 because it seems to be a common one, but it might be not the best for my case

```php
$this->addSql('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;');
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE myTable ADD point geometry(GEOMETRY, 4326)');
$this->addSql('UPDATE myTable SET point = ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(longitude, latitude), 4326)');
```

With raw sql, something like `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_SetSRID(point, 4326)::geography, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4.137325 46.691456)', 4326)::geography, 20000)` seems to work but it is probably not optimised.

And I am struggling with the querybuilder to search elements in a given area around one.
And I would like to sort by proximity.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ends up with the creation of a geography column instead of a geometry, to avoid conversion

```
'ALTER TABLE Creche ADD point geography(point, 4326)'
```

And for the query, using `$qb->expr()->eq` seems to make it work.

```
$exp = "n.point, ST_GeomFromText('" . $entity->getPoint() . "', 4326)";
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n');    
$queryBuilder = $qb
            ->addSelect('st_distance('.$exp.') as distance')
            ->where($qb->expr()->eq("ST_DWithin($exp, " . $rayon * 1000 . ")","true"))
            ->orderBy('distance', 'asc')
            ->setMaxResults(10);
```